# gradle keeps throwing error "Cannot write a file to a location pointing at a directory."

Tags: java, flutter, kotlin, dart, gradle

gradle keeps throwing error while building the project. "Cannot write a file to a location pointing at a directory."[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bS4M.png)

I tried creating a folder named debug in the ancestor directory but it keeps keeps giving the same error

Comment: Instead of adding a screenshot of error, rather copy and paste error as text in the question.

Comment: See: https://docs.gradle.org/7.5/userguide/validation_problems.html#cannot_write_output

Comment: I've the same error and still cannot fix it, but a temp solution every single time before running the app I delete the folder app/build/intermediates